# Open Popup after 5 seconds what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I placed a popup on page load, but I would prefer to appear after 5 seconds. I inserted tie out code, but it is not working what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var link;
        var element;
                    t=setTimeout(openpopupFunction,5000);
        function openPopUp(url)
        {
            link = url;
            element = document.getElementById("background");
            element.style.display = "block";
            element = document.getElementById("popup");
            element.style.display = "block";

        }
</script>
```

Comment: if @Guffas response doesnt answer your question could you put some more context on what you are trying to do? are you literally trying to make a new pop up browser window open?

Comment: I am trying to open a popup signup form when my page loads. I want that window to open after 5 seconds. The body tag is <body onLoad="openPopUp( );">
          <div id="background" class="dimLayer">
          </div>
          <div id="popup" class="popUpDisplay">
<!--popup header-->
      <div  class="popUpTitle"><span style="float:left; font-family: Lucida Grande; font-weight: bold; font-size:24px;margin-left:9px; margin-top:5px; color:  #353535;">
                        Newsletter Sign Up</span> --- and rest of the contents. Hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a different function name when you try to call it. Use:

```
var t = setTimeout(openPopUp, 5000);
```

You only need the variable `t` here if you need to stop the timeout.

Side note: You would normally declare the variables `link` and `element` inside the function so that they are local, not global variables. Try to keep as little as possible in the global scope, to minimise the risk of conflicts between scripts and with other things that are already in the global scope.

Comment: So do I need to replace var link; var element; with var t = setTimeout(openpopUp, 500); ?

Comment: @crv: No, just change the function name that you use in the call.

Comment: I changed the function name, still not working, could you please write up the code? Thanks

Comment: @crv: The only change needed is exactly as the code in the answer. Do you get any error message in the error console?

Comment: @Petty: No, `t` is not a function. It's a handle that you can use with the `clearTimeout` method to stop the timeout.

Comment: @crv you said you changed some code based on suggestions. Can we see what updated code you have?